# UDEV rule not working - can't create symlink

Tags: centos, udev

So, I confess I'm actually trying to study for the Linux+ exam

I have a USB device.  Information about it looks like:

```
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0b.0/usb1/1-2':
    KERNELS=="1-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0781"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="200mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="1234..."
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1372"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="SanDisk"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="5575"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="Cruzer Glide"
```

I attempted to edit a file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules` so it looks a lot like this.

```
KERNELS=="1-2", ATTRS{serial}=="1234...", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0781", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5575", SYMLINK+="myHDD".
```

However, even after I:
`udevadm control --reload-rules` and
`udevadm trigger` and a restart, `lsblk` just returns an error saying myHDD is not a block device.  However, `\dev\myHDD` does seem to exist, and it looks like:

`lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 3 Nov 30 14:33 /dev/myHDD -> sdd`

Could someone please tell me where I have have gone wrong?  (I guess it should be noted there are several partitions on this drive.)  Also, I have no idea where the name of the file comes from... I don't know why it starts with a 10 or anything else. Running on CentOS.